# How to retrieve all the queries(with column name) which are executed in database in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, logging

Good day to all!!

My requirement is like this:
In my web application, I want all the queries which are executed in my database. I have postgres and I did following changes in configuration.

```
log_min_message = debug5;
log_statement='all';
```

Let me give an example: 
Let say, I have table **student** and its definition is like this:

```
create table student(id integer, firstname text, lastname text);
```

**Case 1:** When from my application, I insert a row:

```
insert into student(id,firstname,lastname) values (1,'a','b');
```

I got following things in my log file:

```
2017-03-15 10:12:39.751 GMT :: DEBUG:  parse <unnamed>: insert into student (id, firstname, lastname) values ($1, $2, $3)
2017-03-15 10:12:39.751 GMT :: DEBUG:  StartTransactionCommand
2017-03-15 10:12:39.751 GMT :: DEBUG:  bind <unnamed> to <unnamed>
2017-03-15 10:12:39.751 GMT :: LOG:  execute <unnamed>: insert into student (id, firstname, lastname) values ($1, $2, $3)
2017-03-15 10:12:39.751 GMT :: DETAIL:  parameters: $1 = 1, $2 = 'a', $3 = 'b'
2017-03-15 10:12:39.751 GMT :: DEBUG:  ProcessQuery
2017-03-15 10:12:39.758 GMT :: DEBUG:  CommitTransactionCommand
2017-03-15 10:12:39.758 GMT :: DEBUG:  bind <unnamed> to S_2
2017-03-15 10:12:39.758 GMT :: DEBUG:  StartTransactionCommand
2017-03-15 10:12:39.758 GMT :: LOG:  execute S_2: COMMIT
```

**Case 2:** But when I tried to insert this:

```
insert into student values (2,'a','b');
```

I got this:

```
2017-03-15 10:12:39.751 GMT :: DEBUG:  parse <unnamed>: insert into student values ($1, $2, $3)
    2017-03-15 10:12:39.751 GMT :: DEBUG:  StartTransactionCommand
    2017-03-15 10:12:39.751 GMT :: DEBUG:  bind <unnamed> to <unnamed>
    2017-03-15 10:12:39.751 GMT :: LOG:  execute <unnamed>: insert into student values ($1, $2, $3)
    2017-03-15 10:12:39.751 GMT :: DETAIL:  parameters: $1 = 1, $2 = 'a', $3 = 'b'
    2017-03-15 10:12:39.751 GMT :: DEBUG:  ProcessQuery
    2017-03-15 10:12:39.758 GMT :: DEBUG:  CommitTransactionCommand
    2017-03-15 10:12:39.758 GMT :: DEBUG:  bind <unnamed> to S_2
    2017-03-15 10:12:39.758 GMT :: DEBUG:  StartTransactionCommand
    2017-03-15 10:12:39.758 GMT :: LOG:  execute S_2: COMMIT
```

But I need **fully qualified query with all column names**. (Like the case 1)

```
insert into student (id, firstname, lastname) values ($1, $2, $3)
```

Will it be possible?

Comment: Well why dont write Case 2 same as Case 1? Is very weird you have two different sintaxis. Keep a single standard in all your code to reduce maintenence headaches.

Comment: Agree @JuanCarlosOropeza with you but its a legacy code and there are many places where code is like this. :(

Comment: I dont see an automatic way to do that. I guess you need do a string parsing to insert the fieldnames something like if `<tablename> values` convert to `<tablenames> <fields> values`

Comment: Hmmm... i thought same. But I am thinking that if postgres has such  facility then my life would become easy...